# My font size is small, but my highlight size is huge?

Tags: html, fonts, highlight

When I change the font size of some text, the highlight size doesn't change and it's causing gap between the previous lines.

Date highlight size causing gap between the date and title

[image: image 1]

```
<font size = "3"><small>{{blog.pub_date}}</small></font>
```

Comment: Note: `<font>` tag is obsolete and not supported in HTML5.

Comment: you can do something like this [myfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rrhythmsharma/px68zmdb/2/), ping me with the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that you have a CSS rule controlling the `<small>` tag. While `<small>` would inherit its `font-size` from the parent `<font>` tag, if such a rule exists, it will take priority:

```css
small {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<font size="3">
  <small>{{blog.pub_date}}</small>
</font>
```

Also, please note that the **[`<font>` tag is obsolete](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-font-tag.html)** in itself -- you should the use CSS **[`font-size` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)** instead, as is shown in the snippet above.

Comment: I tried the css rule but, the highlight size is still the same

Answer (score 0):

> Remove small tag should solve your probelm :

```html
<font size = "10">{{blog.pub_date}}</font>
```

Comment: It makes the font bigger and highlight still the same [link](https://imgur.com/a/6Zj5xK7)